# CRM Dynamics 2013 How to change Navigation Bar Organization name and Theme based on Organization

Tags: javascript, css, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a scenario in CRM Dynamics 2013 where I need to change the Organization navigation bar name and color scheme based on which organization is loaded, I have a QA and PROD Organization, when a user opens QA the name should change from Microsoft Dynamics CRM to CRM QA as well as the NAV Bar color, and when user loads PROD it should change from Microsoft Dynamics CRM to CRM PROD and a different NAV Bar Color. How can this be done, can I use JavaScript? , if yes, please advice on where to get more information, I tried to google around but no luck,I know this is not supported to change CRM Controls, but unfortunately our client insist on the change. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the name but this shows how to change the color schema at least: https://andz88.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/crm-on-premise-sandbox-colour-scheme/

And as you said, it is unsupported.